# Strange CollectionView diffable data source crash on ios 17

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, xcode15, ios17, uicollectionviewdiffabledatasource

After using xcode 15 for distribution we are having strange crashes from UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource. Crash does not indicate any call stack from our own code. This happens on %100 ios 17 and with xcode 15.1 build and we can not reproduce it in testing environment. Here is the stack trace

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libswiftCore.dylib             0x40369c swift_getObjectType + 40
1  UIKitCore                      0x469160 __swift_destroy_boxed_opaque_existential_1Tm + 35088
2  UIKitCore                      0x2633ac -[__UIDiffableDataSource collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:] + 144
3  UIKitCore                      0x466fd4 __swift_destroy_boxed_opaque_existential_1Tm + 26500
4  UIKitCore                      0x4670e0 __swift_destroy_boxed_opaque_existential_1Tm + 26768
5  UIKitCore                      0xd2194 -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:isFocused:notify:] + 668
6  UIKitCore                      0x65f674 -[UICollectionView _prefetchItemsForPrefetchingContext:] + 384
7  UIKitCore                      0x32204c -[UICollectionView _updatePrefetchedCells:] + 148
8  UIKitCore                      0x6613fc -[UICollectionView _updateCycleIdleUntil:] + 492
9  UIKitCore                      0xa69a5c ___UIUpdateCycleNotifyIdle_block_invoke + 596
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x213c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x3dd4 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x125a4 _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 988
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x121b8 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 44
14 CoreFoundation                 0x3751c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16
15 CoreFoundation                 0x34218 __CFRunLoopRun + 1996
16 CoreFoundation                 0x33968 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608
17 GraphicsServices               0x34e0 GSEventRunModal + 164
18 UIKitCore                      0x22aedc -[UIApplication _run] + 888
19 UIKitCore                      0x22a518 UIApplicationMain + 340
20 MyApp                          0xd968 main + 42 (AppDelegate.swift:42)
21 ???                            0x1c8366d84 (Missing)
```

End here is the exception:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000000
```

This address is always `0x0000000000000000`.
Anyone having the similar issue?

Comment: In terms of `KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS` see [Investigating memory access crashes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/investigating-memory-access-crashes#Identify-the-type-of-memory-access-that-caused-the-issue), though it is not terribly illuminating. It is a memory issue, so I would suspect some non-thread-safe mutation, but that’s a wild guess. Re not reproducing in test environment, I can only advise trying to build an optimized release build (not debug build) and see if you can reproduce, perhaps turning on exception breakpoint if you succeed in reproducing the crash.

Comment: FWIW, I would not suspect a general problem with diffable data source, as I’ve found it to be pretty bullet-proof (and much easier than the legacy `UICollectionViewDataSource` with far better UX).